# Change sharepoint 2013 message "this shouldn't take long"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, customization

I'm trying to change the loading SharePoint Message : This Shouldn't Take Long...

http://www.ginamontgomery.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/this-shouldnt-take-long.png

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: One vote to migrate this to Sharepoint stackexchange